# Delayed Update of Root Site

Tags: html, css, mysql, nginx, webserver

I am working on a static HTML site (not WordPress/PHP-based) hosted on Siteground.

When I update the index.html, the main site "www.domain.com" takes anywhere from hours to days to update accordingly. However, the page "www.domain.com/index.html" updates immediately.

How can I speed this process up? I've already tried manually flushing the Dynamic Cache, but that doesn't seem to help (and I am testing this on several browsers/devices/after clearing the browser cache/incognito mode).

Comment: Do you have anything else between the server and the visitor? CloudFlare or some other caching mechanism? Are you using any caching system on the server itself, such as `proxy_cache`? 

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Comment: I had this exact problem on Siteground.  Solved by clicking the "flush cache" symbol (a broom) listed under https://my.siteground.com/ > Websites > [website name] > Site Tools > Speed > Caching > Dynamic Cache > Actions.